# Showing limit of an expression containing trigonometric functions

Tags: limits, derivatives, trigonometry

Given $ f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ $f(x) =x + \sin x\cos x$ and $g(x) =f(x) e^{\sin x}$ I have to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists.

I have reached $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1+\cos2x}{e^{\sin x}(1+\cos2x+x\cos x+\sin x \cos^2x)}$ and then I got stuck. Perhaps there is a more intuitive way of doing this or a trick, as I have a feeling it shouldn't look this convoluted.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Nope, you are on the right track. Just to give a hint, what is the dominant term in denominator?

Comment: I'm guessing it's $e^{sinx}$

Comment: We have $\sin x \le |\sin x| \le 1 \Rightarrow e^{\sin x} \le e$. The dominant term is $x \cos x e^{\sin x}$ in denominator, now go from there.

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{e}\leq e^{sinx} \leq e$ and  $|cos(x)| \leq 1$ then that means that $xcosxe^{sinx}$ oscillates between $\infty and -\infty$ and so the function gets closer and closer to 0. Although wouldn't that cause problems when in places where cosx = 0?

Comment: Nice, you found the answer, and no it is not a problem. When $\cos x = 0$ then $x = \pm \frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$ and then $1+\cos2x = 0$ which is our nominator and we get $\frac{0}{0}$. I think we can show the limit exists in those points too except the point itself (the ratio is undefined in $x = \pm \frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$), it takes a little more work though. use $\cos2x = 2\cos x ^2 -1$.